# Web MediaRecorder - slowly upload data to server

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I have an element recording feature that records an element in a user's webpage (given their permission of course). I am able to capture that info over MediaRecorder as a Blob, and before they leave the page, upload the blob to the server via an ajax request. The problem I am facing is that if the data is too large, or if the user leaves too unexpectedly (user shutting down browser), not enough time is given (on window unload) in order to upload videos. Is there a way to constantly be recording and uploading piece by piece to the server with MediaRecorder?

Thanks,

Comment: You can push chunks of MediaRecorder's output to a server with Websockets or socket.io a few tens of milliseconds' worth at a time. This question describes that process.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274558/sending-saving-mediarecorder-data-producing-extremely-glitchy-results